# What would be better for performance in a Neo4J database, many relationships from nodes or reducing relationships by copying subgraphs?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am considering using Neo4j to track multiple users' content that is organized in a graph structure. So a user would create a graph "A", but then another user could link their own content in their own graph "B" to a node in graph "A". Eventually I could have X number of users and hence X relationships stemming from a single node in graph "A" into other graphs.  So at some point, would it be better to copy the nodes from the "A" graph into a new subgraph that "B" can link off of and then own?

It seems to be a relationship indexing versus node indexing problem.

I also heard that newer Neo4J will be improving relationship transversal through hash maps or potentially b-trees which would improve the relationship searching.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the most intuitive representation (no copying). Design what is best for your domain and do the optimizations later if needed. I recommend reading the chapter 'Avoiding Anti-Patterns' in the Graph Databases [book](http://graphdatabases.com/)

Comment: Ah, I love that book!  That's where I got my start with Neo4j.  I'll check that out and then get back to you. Thanks!